# Installing Pygame for Windows 64 for multiple users

Tags: python, pygame, pip

I'm trying to install Pygame for my students. I'm using PIP to install the Windows 64 binaries `.WHL` file. Unfortunately, I'm finding that although it installs for myself (the administrator), for all other users of the computer, they receive an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init' when they try to call `pygame.init()`

To install pygame,

I'm calling

> c:Python34/scripts/  pip install pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: What does "an error of 'no valid module'" mean? Can you show us the full exception with traceback, instead of just describing it?

Comment: The actual error is:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'.  But it works fine under my own profile

Comment: Edit the question to include that, don't just write it in a comment. (Also, that still doesn't include the traceback.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found out why its not working - nothing to do with pygame or pip. It seems the issue is permissions. The **init**.py files isnt able to be read by student users.  If i manual change their permissions for the pygame lib folder it seems to work.